# git pull on EC2 instance accessed by ssh works on some workstations and not others

Tags: amazon-ec2, git

I have two machines at work, a laptop and a desktop.

Both are Ubuntu. Both have synced .ssh folders including the RSA keys. On both I can ssh to our EC2 instance succesfully and work within the EC2 instance via Terminal, run python, etc...

Except git usage. On the tower, `git pull` on my repo works fine. On the laptop, `git pull` on the same repo says permission denied. In both cases I am successfully logged onto the same EC2 instance and working in a terminal window. What could the difference possibly be, that is causing me a permission error?

One possibility is, my laptop is operating through a VPN and the tower is via ethernet. (Our repos are stored in a private bitbucket, not github.) Can this still make a difference, even after I have successfully logged into the EC2 instance and I am working in a terminal? Can it be that even from within the EC2, git somehow reads that I am there via a VPN and denies me the permission?

Answer (score 1):

If you're pulling via SSH, and if you use `ssh-agent` to manage your keys on either the laptop or tower (or both), this could be due to [SSH agent forwarding](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/):

> SSH agent forwarding can be used to make deploying to a server simple. It allows you to use your local SSH keys instead of leaving keys (without passphrases!) sitting on your server.

Even with identical `.ssh` folders on both the laptop and desktop, the agent could be storing a different set of keys on one than on the other.

`ssh-add -L` should list the keys currently stored by the agent.  If the key you use for your repo is listed on one machine, but not on the other (or if the other isn't running ssh-agent at all) then there's your culprit.

Comment: Output is "could not open a connection to your authentication agent". Is it possible this is a VPN issue?

Comment: That means the agent is not running, so it can't be forwarding keys.  If that's the output on both laptop and desktop, then the issue must be something else.  I doubt it's the VPN, though, since as you said it's the EC2 instance making the SSH connection.  

You might have some luck if you SSH in verbose mode from the EC2 instance: `ssh -v git@bitbucket.com`.  If you're successful, it will say `logged in as [username]` and then kick you off with `Shell access is disabled`.  If you're unsuccessful, it should say why.